# Javascript using for web storage

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

Below is the code I have for my website I am trying to build. I keep going over the JavaScript to see if I have errors but can't find where I went wrong. I am trying to let users whom come to my site choose a background color from a drop down menu. I am also trying to make it so that when users come back to my website the background is still the same with the use of web storage. Here is my code below:

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setBackground()
    {
        localstorage.bgColor = document.getElementById("Color_list").value;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgColor;
    }

    function loadBackground()
    {
        if (localStorage.bgColor.length == 0)
        {
            localStorage.bgColor = "White";
        }
        else
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgColor;
            document.getElementById("Color_list").value = localStorage.bgColor;
        }

    }
</script>





<body onLoad="javascript: loadBackground();">

    <select id="Color_list">

        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="Purple">Purple</option>

    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Set Background color" onClick="javascript: setBackground();" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors in this

1. localStorage in place of localstorage inside setBackground method
2. inside loadBackground method do this

   ```
   if (!localStorage.bgColor)
   {
       localStorage.bgColor = "White";
   }
   ```

insead of

```
if (localStorage.bgColor.length == 0)
    {
        localStorage.bgColor = "White";
    }
```

Also, its better setItem and getItem while accessing localStorage's properties

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Why `!localStorage.bgColor` is using?

Comment: if you haven't set the localStorage.bg, localStorage.bg.length will throw an error as its trying to access length property of an obj which is not there . So you will have to check if there is any property set or not first

Comment: Then why `localStorage.bgColor.length == 0` is an error?

Comment: because when u run your code for the first time localStorage.bgColor is undefined and hence its .length will throw an error as its trying to access length property of an obj which is not there

Answer (score 1):

You had a *typo*, try with this change

```
localStorage.bgColor = document.getElementById("Color_list").value; //it was localstorage earlier
```

Answer (score 1):

use `localStorage.setItem('bgColor ', document.getElementById("Color_list").value);`

to set value in local storage